# When using style.filter in browser ie6,ie7,ie8 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I'm using `style.opacity` in (ff,chrome,etc) browsers.
And in (ie6,7,8) I'm using `style.filter` but doesn't work.

And the following is what I did:

```
targetElement.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=30)'; // targetElement is div
```

The previous code works fine in **ie9** only, but doesn't work in **ie6,7,8** . why?

Comment: What exactly mean it doesn't work? What elements you have in the `DIV`? `alpha(opacity=30)` works even in IE5, so there's something strange going on, please post more code.

Comment: Question: Given that IE9 supports the standard `opacity` style, are you sure that it isn't your standard code that is working in IE rather than the filter? I don't see any reason for the filter to work in IE9 but not other IEs, but if it's failing consistently but your `style.opacity` is working in IE9, then things make a lot more sense.

Comment: I have to say that I've never tried setting the filter style using Javascript. It always seemed too much of a hassle (especially with the inherent quirks around the `filter` style). It does work: jQuery is able to fade elements in and out in IE using it, but it's still a hassle. My advice: it would make things a lot easier if you simply put the opacity styles into a CSS class, and changed the class name using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no alpha transparency filter for IE 6 and 7. You can use a gradient filter as workaround/hack by setting the same color for start and end. MS gradient filter can handle RGB with alpha transparancy.

Half transparent, nearly black background (the alpha channel is the first two hex digits):

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr=#E5333333, endColorstr=#E5333333 );
-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr=#E5333333, endColorstr=#E5333333 );
```

Comment: no, filter opacity always worked even in older IEs. In any case, the question here isn't with the filter style itself, which the OP is clearly familiar with, but with setting it via Javascript.